# how to design my dataset using neo4j and gremlin

Tags: neo4j, cypher, gremlin

i have a dataset containg fields like below:

```
id  amount date        s_pName   s_cName      b_pName   b_cName

 1    100   2/3/2012      IBM    IBM_USA        Pepsi    Pepsi_USA  
 2    200   21/3/2012     IBM    IBM_USA        Coke     Coke_UK
 3    300   12/3/2012     IBM    IBM_USA        Pepsi    Pepsi_USA
 4    1100  22/3/2012     Pepsi  IBM_Aus        IBM      IBM_USA
```

here all 4 fields like s_pName   s_cName      b_pName   b_cName can be **saler or buyer.**
how to models this dataset in neo4j so that when I query using gremlin like,

select b_CName,id,amount,date from tableName where s_cName = IBM_USA,IBM_AUS;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noted your question on the gremlin-users mailing list as well (where you provided a bit more information about things you'd tried): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gremlin-users/AxsF2eJvpOA

I'm sure there are a few ways to approach this modelling issue, so I'll just provide some things to consider and hopefully that will inspire you to solution.  First, instead of thinking of buyers and sellers, just think about the fact that you have "companies" that sells things to other companies and that companies have hierarchy (meaning that a company can have a parent).  Your model then comes down to:

```
company --sellsTo--> company
company --parent--> company
```

Place your transaction amount and date on the "sellsTo" edge creating one such edge per row in your dataset.  Create a key index on the "companyName" field of the company vertex so that you can look up the company.  Your Gremlin would then be something like:

```
['IBM_USA','IBM_AUS'].collect{g.V('companyName',it).next()}._().outE('sellsTo').as('tx').inV.as('buyer').select{[it.id, it.amount, it.date]}{it.companyName}
```

so breaking that down you do a lookup of your two companies you care about by key index on `companyName` and get them into a pipeline with `_()`.  Then you traverse out to the companies those two companies sold to.  You use `select` to grab the `tx` (transaction edge) and `buyer` vertex executing a closure on each of them to transform them into the fields you want which will yield you something like (for one result, your Gremlin would likely return several of these with your full dataset obviously):

```
[[1,100,2/3/2012],Pepsi_USA]
```

You could use some Groovy JDK (http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/) operations to transform it further from there if that's not the final format you need.

Comment: thanx stephen. one doubt.. so initially while creating nodes and edges. should I create customerNode with attribues . consider first row (IBM_USA and PEPSI_USA) for paring them ?

Comment: Your load strategy, given the model I provided, would be to loop through each row of data, look up the "company" vertex by the key index I on the companyName field I suggested you create.  If it does not exist then create it.  Do that for buyer and seller fields (for both the child and parent) and build the "parent" edge between them if either is new.  Your final step will be to add the "sellsTo" edge.  You should be able to do all this in one pass of the file.

Comment: I don't know your exact datasize, but consider using BatchGraph (https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Batch-Implementation).  It will help make the code for this easier.